# How to tell if it's either the CPU or the Motherboard that is bad?

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard

I have an Acer 5536 laptop that won't boot. I've already tested the memory modules and the hard drive and both are ok. The problem is that I don't know how to tell which one is the problem: the CPU or the Motherboard. To diagnose it I removed everything except the most fundamental parts (the RAM and the CPU) and the peripherals that could not be removed like the USB 2.0 multi-card reader. These are the symptoms when attempting to turn on:

- The power led turns on.
- The DVD drive makes startup sounds.
- Fan spins for about 5 seconds then shuts down.
- Screen is blank (not even the backlight is lit).
- No beep is heard whatsoever.
- It won't turn off by itself, even afer several minutes, it'd just stay like that until I press the power button for 6 seconds.

I don't have enough experience with faulty systems as to correctly tell if it's the CPU or the Motherboard, plus I am not (yet) able to open it completely as to remove the CPU to test it individually (and I don't have a spare AMD motherboard to test it). Since the owner wants to know how much will it cost, I'd just simply tell them the price of both a new motherboard and CPU and spare me a lot of trouble, but I think I would feel like I'm ripping them off. I hope you can help me.

Comment: In my experience, its kinda hard. I once was getting thrown cpu errors when my motherboard had some physical damage. To make things more fun, it might also be a GPU error

Comment: The obvious thing to do is verify to the best of your capacity that no pins are bent.  Because what you describe would be explained by a bent pin on the cpu socket.  If thats the case you need a new motherboard.

Comment: I think these models use LGA rather than PGA so a bent pin (I assume on the CPU) won't be the issue, and by the way this machine has never been opened so there's no way it got bent I think...

Answer (score 0):

When I've come upon this situation before I've just told the owner what was going on and asked what they wanted to do. You could replace both, or find the cheapest part to replace and start with it. You may get lucky.

I'd say to pull the ram and listen for a beep, since it should yell if the ram is bad or missing, but there is no way I've found to guarantee that if it beeps the mobo or cpu is the culprit. I would say that generally, the mobo is the culprit, but it's a crap shoot and so I would just be honest with the owner about the issue, they may not even want to bother with a repair and buy new anyways.